# Random numbers are the same when used in the FOR command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So i'm working on a "Minesweeper level generator" and this is the code to set the text to be displayed in positions. (□ is Clear, O is a bomb (working on the number indicators))

```
for %%v in (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8,f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,g1,g2,g3,g4,g5,g6,g7,g8,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,h7,h8) do (
if %bombs% gtr 0 (if %random% gtr 16383 (set e_a1=O && set /a "bombs-=1") else (set e_%%v=□))
)
```

or this:

```
for %%v in (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8,f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,g1,g2,g3,g4,g5,g6,g7,g8,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,h7,h8) do (
set _r=
set /a "_r=(%RANDOM%*6/32768)+1"
if %bombs% gtr 0 (if %_r% gtr 3 (set e_a1=O && set /a "bombs-=1") else (set e_%%v=□))
)
```

It should work fine, but when I tried this out in cmd, I found that all the assigned random numbers are the same each time.

Why does it do that and how can I fix it?

Comment: `Enable DelayedExpansion`, and use `!RANDOM!` and `!_r!`.

Comment: Tried replacing %random% with !random! (and enabled delayed expansion)

Comment: Now it's now always 15

Comment: Without you posting sufficient code for us to reproduce your issue, it is unlikely we will be able to assist you further. Please post enough code for us to be able to run ourselves. We need the code in which `bombs` was defined and an indication of nesting levels, and the code you're using to show/view the expanded variables values. Please see [mcve], for a better understanding of the expectations.

Comment: @SeanArmecin, what is always 15?   If you updated any code, then [edit] your question so we know what the current state of the code is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FOR /L %%c IN (1,1,8) DO FOR %%b IN (a b c d e f g h) DO CALL SET /a #%%b%%c=1 + (%%random%% %%%% 6)
SET #
```

`#` prefixed to variablename for ease of display of results

Comment: Fixed! New code: 
`for /L %%c in (1,1,8) do for %%b in (a b c d e f g h) do (
set /a "_r=(%RANDOM%*6/32768)+1"
if !bombs! gtr 0 (if !_r! gtr 3 (set e_%%b%%c=O && set /a "bombs-=1") else (set e_%%b%%c=□)) else (set e_%%b%%c=□)
)
`
Thanks to your help!

Comment: @SeanArmecin, while Magoo's code does provide for better readability, it is not what solved your code issues.  The use of Delayed Expansion is what solved your code issue so I am not sure why you chose to mark this as the answer to your question.  No offense to you Magoo. Your code is always solid.